# Apache Tomcat 7 on Centos 6 writing logs to /var/log/messages

Tags: java, logging, tomcat7, syslog

We have several instances of Apache Tomcat 7.0.57 running on Linux CentOS release 6.3, with Java jdk1.7.0_80.

I am kind of new in this company, and one of my first tasks is to find out why Tomcat is writing logs to `/var/log/messages` Log in addition to writing to standard `catalina.out` and `catalina.log` Files.

This is confusing and annoying because if you want to troubleshoot a Linux issue, that log will be flooded with thousands of Tomcat messages/errors.

Comment: was tomcat installed from tgz or via yum packages ?

Comment: It was installed via TGZ since original Tomcat for Centos 6.3 was Tomcat 6

Comment: do you have log4j*.xml files under your tomcat directory or webapps/ directories ?

Comment: I have a log4j.properties in the only deployed app.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/1d3nw